# Highcharts/Highstock How to show original OHLC values in tooltip for chart drawn using adjusted OHLC values?

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, shared

This snippet shows both original OHLC and adjusted OHLC data in separate plots:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
  How to show original values in tooltip?
</title>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart-container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<pre id="csv" style="display: none">
date,open,high,low,close,volume,ex_dividend,split_ratio,adj_open,adj_high,adj_low,adj_close,adj_volume
2014-05-30,637.98,644.17,628.9,633.0,20143600.0,0.0,1.0,85.783881043984,86.616199022075,84.562968727173,85.114261733663,141005200.0
2014-06-02,633.96,634.83,622.5,628.65,13191100.0,0.0,1.0,85.243344974207,85.36032666095,83.702413790213,84.529353299948,92337700.0
2014-06-03,628.46,638.74,628.25,637.54,10453900.0,0.0,1.0,84.503805575257,85.886071942748,84.475568616388,85.724717892068,73177300.0
2014-06-04,637.44,647.89,636.11,644.82,11981500.0,0.0,1.0,85.711271721178,87.116396579183,85.532437648341,86.70359913286,83870500.0
2014-06-05,646.2,649.3699,642.61,647.35,10850200.0,0.0,1.0,86.889156291142,87.315386462184,86.406438756191,87.043787256377,75951400.0
2014-06-06,649.9,651.26,644.47,645.57,12497800.0,0.0,1.0,87.386664614072,87.569532538176,86.656537534745,86.804445414535,87484600.0
2014-06-09,92.7,93.88,91.75,93.7,75414997.0,0.0,7.0,87.252202905172,88.362856620685,86.358032540987,88.193434867471,75414997.0
2014-06-10,94.73,95.05,93.57,94.25,62777000.0,0.0,1.0,89.16290378864,89.464098016576,88.071074712372,88.711112446736,62777000.0
2014-06-11,94.13,94.76,93.47,93.86,45681000.0,0.0,1.0,88.59816461126,89.191140747509,87.976951516142,88.344031981439,45681000.0
2014-06-12,94.04,94.12,91.9,92.29,54749000.0,0.0,1.0,88.513453734653,88.588752291637,86.499217335332,86.866297800629,54749000.0
2014-06-13,92.2,92.44,90.88,91.28,54525000.0,0.0,1.0,86.781586924022,87.007482594974,85.539160733786,85.915653518706,54525000.0
2014-06-16,91.51,92.75,91.45,92.2,35561000.0,0.0,1.0,86.132136870035,87.299264503287,86.075662952297,86.781586924022,35561000.0
</pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
Highcharts.stockChart('chart-container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Plot Title',
    align: 'left',
    floating: false
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: true,
    sourceWidth: 900,
    sourceHeight: 600
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false,
    floating: true,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    align:'center'
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    buttons: [{
      type: 'month',
      count: 6,
      text: '6m'
    }, {
      type: 'year',
      count: 1,
      text: '1y'
    }, {
      type: 'year',
      count: 2,
      text: '2y'
    }, {
      type: 'year',
      count: 3,
      text: '3y'
    }, {
      type: 'year',
      count: 4,
      text: '4y'
    }, {
      type: 'all',
      text: 'All'
    }],
  selected: 3
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      visible: false,
      turboThreshold: 0 // Comment out this code to display error
    },
    ohlc: {
      color: 'black'
    }
  },
  data: {
    csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
    firstRowAsNames: false,
    startRow: 1,
    seriesMapping: [{
        x: 0,
        open: 1,
        high: 2,
        low: 3,
        close: 4
    }, {
        x: 0,
        open: 8,
        high: 9,
        low: 10,
        close: 11
    }, {
        x: 0,
        y: 9
    }, {
        x: 0,
        y: 10
    }]
  },
  series: [{
        name: 'Values',
        type: 'ohlc', // bars
        visible: true,
        // set color in plotOptions
        tooltip: {
        // set tooltip options here
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Adj_Values',
        type: 'ohlc', // bars
        visible: true,
        // set color in plotOptions
        tooltip: {
        // set tooltip options here
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Adj_High',
        type: 'line', // high
        visible: false,
        color: 'blue'
    }, {
        name: 'Adj_Low',
        type: 'line', // low
        visible: false,
        color: 'gray'
    }]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If possible I want to (1) make the original OHLC plot invisible; (2) plot only the adjusted OHLC bars; and (3) show the original OHLC values in the tooltip attached to the adjusted OHLC bars shown in the plot.

I can find examples of a shared tooltip but no information on the options that would replace the adjusted OHLC with original OHLC data. Alternatively I might want to add original OHLC data to show both original and adjusted in the tooltip associated with the adjusted data plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable `visible` property for the first series and use tooltip's formatter function to find a matched point from the hidden series and show it's values.

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function(tooltip) {
            const originalFormat = tooltip.defaultFormatter.call(this, tooltip);
            const point = this.points[0].point;
            const originalPoint = tooltip.chart.series[0].points.find(
                p => p.x === point.x
            );

            originalFormat[1] = `<span style="color:black">●</span> <b> ${point.series.name}</b><br/>Open: ${originalPoint.open}<br/>High: ${originalPoint.high}<br/>Low: ${originalPoint.low}<br/>Close: ${originalPoint.close}<br/>`;
            return originalFormat;

        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Values',
        type: 'ohlc',
        visible: false
    }, {
        name: 'Adj_Values',
        type: 'ohlc',
        visible: true
    }, ...]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k2mhvdp6/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter